# QGIS EditForm Layout Settings in Python

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3, qgis-3

I want to design Editor Forms in QGIS 3.4 programmatically via QGIS' Python API.

Step 1: Setting Editors and human readable names for fields works fine via calls to

```
QgsVectorLayer.setEditorWidgetSetup() 
QgsVectorLayer.setFieldAlias()
```

Step 2: Introduce Tab boxes in my Form works as well 
I tried to switch to using QgsEditFormConfig.EditorLayout.TabLayout, but this does not work:

```
editFormConfig = layer.editFormConfig()
editFormConfig.setLayout(1)
editFormConfig.addTab(....)
layer.setEditFormConfig(editFormConfig)
```

My question is: how can I connect editorWidgetSetup settings from step 1 with those Tab boxes, setting the order of elements and which item is on which tab box?

Comment: Although you stated that it doesn't work `editFormConfig = layer.editFormConfig() editFormConfig.setLayout(1) layer.setEditFormConfig(editFormConfig)` was finally the thing I needed to change the form config to TabLayout (Drag and Drop). I don't know why it's that complicated but thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

To awnser my own question:

First, clear the whole Editor config, and then add QgsAttibuteEditorField elements in the order you like them on the editor widget, finally saving:

```
rootContainer = editFormConfig.invisibleRootContainer()
rootContainer.clear()
editorField = QgsAttributeEditorField(fieldname, index, rootcontainer)
rootContainer.addChildElement(editorField)
...
layer.setEditFormConfig(editFormConfig)
```

To get Entries on the Tab boxes, you need to create QgsAttributeEditorField items with the Tab Boxes as Parent Containers.